# Using global catalog in a ldap search with C# library Novell

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, novell

Until now I was always using the System.DirectoryServices in my c# application. Due to the fact that I want to use a container platform which doesn't support this library I wanted to use the Novell LDAP library.

Until now the connection string looked like this:

```
new Directoryentry("GC://domain.com")
```

I tried it with the Novell library like this:

```
LDAPConnection().connect("GC://domain.com",389);
```

I always get the error message "INVALID ADDRESS". I also tried it without the GC infront of the domain, but then I always get an empty search result.

Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `System.DirectoryServices` classes are for Active Directory exclusively. I don't think they support the Novell systems - for that, you'd have to resort to using the low-level ADSI (Active Directory Services Interface) library (which works with Novell - I know from my own personal experience with it - both Novell bindery as well as Novell NDS systems).

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your comment. My goal was to not use System.DirectoryServices, but instead use Novell or any other library since System.DirectoryServices doesn't work in my linux based container.

Answer (score 0):

The global catalog (GC) uses port 3268, not 389. You usually either use `GC://`, which sets the port for you, or use `LDAP://` along with specifying the port. It depends on the library. If the Novell library doesn't support `GC://`, then just specify the port. According to [the documentation](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/jldap/jldapenu/api/com/novell/ldap/LDAPConnection.html#connect(java.lang.String,%20int)), it doesn't seem to even require `LDAP://`, but I've never used it.

```
LDAPConnection().connect("example.com", 3268);
```